# stateful session bean pool size

Tags: ejb

am going through enterprise session bean material.i have doubts regarding below oints :-

1) lets say we mentioned the pool size as 50 for some statful session bean. Different 50 clients use them . 
so now all the 50 beans maintain some state. At what point of time will these states be removed so that 
if 51th clien ask for bean it does not get any previous spoilt state.?

2) lets say we mentioned the pool size as 50 for some stateless session bean and all are in use at some 
point of time. If 51th client comes and ask for a bean, will that wait till some bean become free 
or create new bean instance?

Comment: This is all vendor-specific.  Which EJB container are you using?  I suggest adding a "glassfish", "openejb", "weblogic", "websphere", etc. tags to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stateful session beans are not normally pooled. It's possible, but their state makes them less ideal to pool as the client expects a fresh bean when obtaining a reference.

For stateless beans, yes the 51st client will have to wait. This is normally a good thing since it automatically moderates the resource consumption of your system. Depending on the resources you have, your workload and the amount of work being to in a single call to a ssb, you might want to tune the size of your pool.

Comment: Thanks Mike one more question on above do we mention the pool size for a specific bean or is it collective for all stateless session bean in application?  and when these instance gets added in pool. Does it happen when the request comes in or on the start up of server?

Comment: The instance pool size can be set for a single bean. You don't know when the instance is added to the pool, but it's typically on demand for stateless session beans. For singleton session beans you can use an annotation to say you want the bean to be created on the start up of the server.

Answer (score 5):

As bkail states the pooling semantics of @Stateless beans are vendor-specific.  That said in EJB 3.1 we added the `@AccessTimeout` annotation which can be used on the bean class or methods of a `@Stateless`, `@Stateful` or `@Singleton` bean.

## @AccessTimeout

In a general sense this annotation portably specifies up to how long a caller will wait if a wait condition occurs with concurrent access.  Specific to each bean type, wait conditions will occur when:

- `@Singleton` - an `@Lock(WRITE)` method is being invoked and container-managed concurrency is being used.  All methods are `@Lock(WRITE)` by default.
- `@Stateful` - any method of the instance is being invoked and a second invocation occurs.  OR the @Stateful bean is in a transaction and the caller is invoking it from outside that transaction.
- `@Stateless` - no instances are available in the pool. As noted, however, pooling sematics, if any, are not covered by the spec.  If the vendor's pooling semantics do involve a wait condition, the @AccessTimeout should apply.

## Usage

The `@AccessTimeout` is simply a convenience wrapper around the `long` and `TimeUnit` tuples commonly used in the `java.util.concurrent` API.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface AccessTimeout {
    long value();
    TimeUnit unit() default TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS; 
}
```

When explicitly set on a bean class or method, it has three possible meanings:

- `@AccessTimeout(-1)` - Never timeout, wait as long as it takes.  Potentially forever.
- `@AccessTimeout(0)` - Never wait. Immediately throw `ConcurrentAccessException` if a wait condition would have occurred.
- `@AccessTimout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` - Wait up to 30 seconds if a wait condition occurs.  After that, throw `ConcurrentAccessTimeoutExcpetion`

## No standard default

Note that the `value` attribute has no default.  This was intentional and intended to communicate that if `@AccessTimeout` is not explicitly used, the behavior you get is vendor-specific.

Some vendors will wait for a preconfigured time and throw `javax.ejb.ConcurrentAccessException`, some vendors will throw it immediately.  When we were defining this annotation it became clear that all of us vendors were doing things a bit differently and enforcing a default would cause problems for existing apps.

On a similar note, prior to EJB 3.0 there was no default transaction attribute and it was different for every vendor.  Thank goodness EJB 3.0 was different enough that we could finally say, "For EJB 3.0 beans the default is REQUIRED."

Comment: As per [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/AccessTimeout.html) `@AccessTimeout` can be only applied on stateful session bean or on a singleton session bean. Even [the EJB spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3.1-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_1-fr-spec.pdf) mention same w.r.t those two. Can you elaborate on your statement - ... `@AccessTimeout` annotation which can be used on the bean class or methods of a `@Stateless`...? EDIT: I would like to know the source of your statement.